# inserting another row in mysql database with values similar to previous row

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table like,

```
BatchID Volume1 Volume2 Volume3

1        3.0      4.0     5.0
1        2.0      1.0     2.0
2        1.0      2.0     4.0 
2        1.0      1.0     1.0
2        1.0      1.0     1.0
```

I am trying to add another batchid 3 with same volume1, volume2 and volume3 values
such that it looks like (same records from batchID 2)

```
1        3.0      4.0     5.0
1        2.0      1.0     2.0
2        1.0      2.0     4.0 
2        1.0      1.0     1.0
2        1.0      1.0     1.0
3        1.0      2.0     4.0 
3        1.0      1.0     1.0
3        1.0      1.0     1.0
```

I wrote the following query

```
insert into table1 (BatchID,Volume1,Volume2,Volume3) Values 
(`3`,Select Volume1,Volume2,Volume3 from table1 where batchid = '2')
```

gives an error.

P.S I know the above is not a good database design. This is over simplified version of my actual design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (BatchID, Volume1, Volume2, Volume3)
SELECT 3, Volume1, Volume2, Volume3 FROM table1 WHERE batchid = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER: I haven't tested this, so try it at your own risk!

Would this work?

```
INSERT INTO table1 (BatchID, Volume1, Volume2, Volume3)
    SELECT 3, Volume1, Volume2, Volume3
    FROM table1
    WHERE BatchID = 2;
```

Comment: This works! unfortunately I can accept only one.. :-( but up voted it none the less.. :-P

Comment: No worries, thanks for the upvote.  eggyal is a smart cookie and a fast typer to boot.  :)

Comment: :) I don't have any chocolate chips though - and everyone knows that a cookie without chocolate chips is hardly a cookie at all.